# Is it possible to dynamically create dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Good evening, kinda new to Python here.

So, I've been working to facebook data analysis project, in which, at first, I need to retrieve all the necessary information. I want to make my code as clean and as "friendly" as possible. While I'm having a really hard time concerning the first thing (the code runs perfectly but it's veeeeery slow, I'm using too many for loops I think), I'm kinda satisfied concerning "user-friendliness". Right now, an hypothetical user only has to type in the metrics/timeframes he needs, automatically prompted at startup, and the program retrieves and transforms into csv files everything.

I'm using 4 different pandas DataFrames for storage, grouping information whose graph object is identical except for index/variable, so that I can easily build a for loop. For example:

```
def scrape_insights(insights,post_ids):
data_insights = pd.DataFrame(columns = insights)

i = 0
while i < len(post_ids):
    print('INSIGHTS DATA: Post {0} out of {1} - processed'.format(i+1,len(post_ids)))
    for j in insights:

        temp = graph.get_connections(id = post_ids[i]['id'], connection_name = 'insights', metric = j)      

        if temp['data'][0]['name'] == j:
            data_insights.at[i,j] = temp['data'][0]['values'][0]['value']

    i += 1  

del(i)
del(j)
del(temp)

return data_insights
```

This function takes as input the list of post insights metrics needed by the user + the list of all the post ids of the related page and returns a dataframe in which every column represents a metric. I'm doing this for post insights, post basic information (I need to use get_object instead of get_connections because I'm dumb and don't manage to merge the two things), page insights and page demographics information.
Now, I have problems regarding the latter. Page demographics information doesn't come as index + value, but for every index (dates this time) I have A LOT of variables (one for each country or language or city etc). 
This means that the result of every call is itself a dataframe: I can't compose my dataframe inside the for loop as before. But I would like the code to work as for the other instances: user inputs the metrics he needs, those are passed to a function which returns the data. It's not a problem to have one complete dataframe for each metric, but I don't understand how I can build them "all at once"...

```
def scrape_demographics(metric_demo, start_date):
data_cities = pd.DataFrame()
temp = graph.get_connections(id = page_id, connection_name = 'insights', metric = metric_demo, since = start_date)
for i in range(0,len(temp['data'][0]['values'])):
    for j in temp['data'][0]['values'][i]['value'].keys():
        data_cities.at[i,j] = temp['data'][0]['values'][i]['value'][j]
        data_cities.at[i,'Date'] = temp['data'][0]['values'][i]['end_time']

return data_cities
```

This works with every demographics metric, I've tried to put countries or languages or whatever, as long as the structure is the same, it works.
What I can do now: create one dataframe for each metric in the main, pass them to the function one at a time, no problem.
What I would like to do: user inputs 2 different metrics, so 2 dataframes are created named as the metric (like two columns would have been created when the metric was single-columned), each of them is passed to the function, and then I have 2 dataframes to convert into csv.

Is it possible to do that? How can I? Should I use classes?

Thank you very very much in advance, and I apologize both for the scarce knowledge of Python I have and for my English (it's not my first language)

Comment: Could you condense this somewhat?

Comment: yes, just the last paragraph is enough to understand my problem: What I can do now: create one dataframe for each metric in the main, pass them to the function one at a time, no problem. What I would like to do: user inputs 2 different metrics, so 2 dataframes are created named as the metric (like two columns would have been created when the metric was single-columned), each of them is passed to the function, and then I have 2 dataframes to convert into csv.

Is it possible to do that? How can I? Should I use classes?